# Constrain the number of threads spawned by Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

By default Tensorflow spawns threads equal to the number of available CPU on my host. Is there anyway to restrict this number? I tried changing the value of `intra_op_parallelism` and `inter_op_parallelism` but the number of spawned threads is always equal to the CPU count on my machine.

Comment: if you set those two settings corrrectly but still have more than 100% utilization from a single session.run that sounds like a bug

Comment: No. I used htop to inspect the process and always saw the # threads equal to the number of CPUs on the host, regardless of intra/inter parallelism thread count.

Comment: does it affect CPU utilization? Setting those settings to 1 will cap utilization at 1 (one active thread at a time)

Comment: Yes. It affects the CPU utilization. But I want to constraint the total # of threads Tensorflow spawns.

Comment: There's no setting to do this. Limiting number of threads leads to hard to debug deadlock situations and threads are considered to be cheap resources. For instance, every dequeue op in the graph will create its own thread.

Comment: @Jes Did you find a solution for restricting the number of threads to 1?